# Clojure Ring auto-refresh script for error screen

Tags: clojure, refresh, ring

When `:auto-reload? true`, Ring injects an auto refresh `<script>` tag via its internal `wrap-reload` middleware whenever you return a status full HTML page. However, this auto-refresh script is not included when an error occurs. As a result, I have to manually refresh the page.

How can I tell Ring to inject an auto-refresh script into its error screen as well?

This is in my `project.clj`:

```
:ring {:handler my-app.handler/app
       :auto-reload? true
       :auto-refresh? true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the auto-refresh is added to the successful response, perhaps it needs to also be added to the error response. You could add a custom error response that returns a 500 error whose body includes the auto refresh script.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of Ring. Can you point me in the right direction? Is there a fn to include the script? How do I override the error response?

Comment: there is a good example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627410/idiomatic-way-to-catch-exceptions-in-ring-apps in the :body you would put the page contents that trigger the redirect